# I'm using Bootstrap in my website but it's not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use bootstrap in my website but it's not responsive. I have also tried using one row grid system, and in row div I used two `col` of sizes 3 and 9.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

ul.nav-pills {
  top: 100px;
  position: fixed;
}

div.col-sm-9 div {
  height: 250px;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.bg-1 {
  background-color: black;
}

.bg-1 ul li {
  color: #ecf0f1;
  font-family: 'Gugi', cursive;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.bg-2 {
  width: 86%;
  background-color: #d1d8e0;
}

.col-sm-3 {
  width: 14% !important;
  background-color: white !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 810px) {
  #about,
  #education,
  #certifications,
  #skills,
  #projects,
  #experience,
  #interest {
    margin-left: 150px;
  }
}

#myScrollspy {
  position: fixed;
  align-self: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#hello {
  font-family: 'Black Han Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 65px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

#name {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-left: 150px;
  /*margin-top: 30px;*/
}

#self {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#engineer {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#intro {
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #d1d8e0;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

hr {
  width: 400px;
  border-top: 1px solid #4b6584;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4b6584;
}

#education {
  margin-top: 300px;
}

#email {
  font-size: 10px;
}

#headings {
  font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: #343a40;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 50px;
}

#social {
  margin-top: -90px;
  margin-left: 250px;
}

.image {
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 1px;
}

.subheadings {
  font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: #20bf6b;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 40px;
}

#certifications {
  margin-top: 300px;
}

.nav-pills>li.active>a,
.nav-pills>li.active>a:focus,
.nav-pills>li.active>a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  /* background-color: #337ab7; */
  background-color: unset !important;
}

#Date {
  margin-left: 60%;
  margin-top: -84px;
}

h5 {
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#skills {
  margin-top: 320px;
}

.devicons {
  font-size: 5rem !important;
}

#projects {
  margin-top: 200px;
}

#experience {
  margin-top: 300px;
}

#interest {
  margin-top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Black+Han+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gugi" rel="stylesheet">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-8iPTk2s/jMVj81dnzb/iFR2sdA7u06vHJyyLlAd4snFpCl/SnyUjRrbdJsw1pGIl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira+Extra+Condensed:400,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konpa/devicon/df6431e323547add1b4cf45992913f15286456d3/devicon.min.css">
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="20">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row bg-1">
      <!--  Left Side Navigation Bar -->
      <div class="col-sm-3 text-center" id="backg">
        <nav id="myScrollspy">

          <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked ">
            <img class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block image" src="naqqash.png" height="150" width="150 ">
            <li class="active"><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#education">EDUCATION</a></li>
            <li><a href="#certifications">CERTIFICATIONS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#skills">SKILLS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects">PROJECTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#experience">EXPERIENCE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#interest">INTEREST</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

      </div>
      <!--  Right Side  -->
      <div class="col-sm-9 bg-2">
        <!-- About -->
        <div id="about">
          <h1 id="hello">hello</h1>
          <h3 id="name">I'm Muhammad Naqqash,</h3>
          <h3 id="self">a self taught developer.</h3>
          <h3 id="engineer">I'm a Computer Engineer. </h3>
          <p id="intro">I'm a positive and friendly person. Also, I love to set goals and achieve them.<br> My important qualities: self-motivated, ability overcome difficulties and the <br> ability to learn.</p>

          <div id="social">
            <a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-lg"></i><span style="display:inline-block; width: 5px;"></span>
                  <a href=""><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-lg"></i></a> <span style="display:inline-block; width: 0px;"></span>
            <a href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-lg"></i></a><span style="display:inline-block; width: 5px;"></span>
            <a href=""><i class="fab fa-github-square fa-lg"></i></a><span style="display:inline-block; width: 5px;"></span>

          </div>


        </div>

        <!-- education -->
        <div id="education">
          <div>
            <h1 id="headings">EDUCATION</h1>
            <h2 class="subheadings1"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap fa-sm"></i><span style="display:inline-block; width: 20px;"></span>BS Computer Engineering</h2>
            <h3 class="subheadings2"><i class="fas fa-university fa-sm"></i><span style="display:inline-block; width: 30px;"></span>NUST College of E&ME</h3>
            <h3 id="Date">2014-18</h3>
          </div>


        </div>
        <div id="certifications">
          <div>
            <h1 id="headings">Certifications</h1>
            <h2 class="subheadings1"><i class="fas fa-certificate fa-sm"></i><span style="display:inline-block; width: 20px;"></span>Microsoft Office Specialist</h2>
            <h5>Microsoft</h5>
            <h2 class="subheadings1"><i class="fas fa-certificate fa-sm"></i><span style="display:inline-block; width: 20px;"></span>The Web Developer Bootcamp</h2>
            <h5>Udemy</h5>
            <h2 class="subheadings1"><i class="fas fa-certificate fa-sm"></i><span style="display:inline-block; width: 20px;"></span>Wordpress Customization</h2>
            <h5>Udemy</h5>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="skills">
          <div>
            <h1 id="headings">Skills</h1>
            <h3>Programming Languages & Tools</h3>
            <div class="devicons">
              <i class="devicon-html5-plain "></i>
              <i class="devicon-css3-plain"></i>
              <i class="devicon-bootstrap-plain"></i>
              <i class="devicon-javascript-plain"></i>
              <i class="devicon-jquery-plain"></i>
              <i class="devicon-wordpress-plain"></i>
              <i class="devicon-cplusplus-plain"></i>
              <i class="devicon-illustrator-plain"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="projects">
          <div>
            <h1 id="headings">Projects</h1>
            <div style="font-size:3em; color: black;">
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-github"></i>
    
                    </a><span style="display:inline-block; width: 40px;"></span>
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-codepen"></i></a>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
        <div id="experience">
          <div>
            <h1 id="headings">Experience</h1>
            <h2 class="subheadings1"><i class="fas fa-globe fa-sm"></i><span style="display:inline-block; width: 20px;"></span>Teaching & Management</h2>
            <h5>Taught Physics, Chemistry & Mathematics. Key role in managing test sessions, class schedules and Provide full learning experience and support for students beyond set classes, working with pupils experiencing barriers to learning across the
              academic range.</h5>
            <br>
            <h2 class="subheadings1"><i class="fas fa-globe fa-sm"></i><span style="display:inline-block; width: 20px;"></span>Career Counselling</h2>
            <h5>Have done many seminars on career counselling and motivational lectures in many educational institutes.
            </h5>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div id="interest">
          <div>
            <h1 id="headings">Interest</h1>
            <i class="fas fa-code fa-lg"></i><span style="display:inline-block; width: 40px;"></span>
            <i class="fas fa-plane fa-lg "></i><span style="display:inline-block; width: 40px;"></span>
            <i class="fas fa-music fa-lg"></i>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: There's a mistake somewhere within your <style> tags causing all your elements to go out of whack. Think about rebuilding it with bootstrap in mind or try and debug (F12 -> Inspect Element) to find exactly where it is caused.
I don't use flat CSS so I can't be of assistance there, but when removing the <style> tag I'm met with a boot-strappy style page, formatted fine.

Comment: there's also something wrong with html, I think missing tag or closing tag

Comment: Your text will scale better if you define font-size in 'em' units rather than 'px'

Comment: missing </html> closing tag

Comment: You also have duplicates of the ID Headings over 10x.    these should be classes if used more than once.